# mysql data not updated using JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I've been stucked with my problem for almost 3 days. Been searching through internet for the solution.

I'm developing an android program that use JSON and php mysql for data management. My main revision is from here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/.

Here is my JSON Parser code:`

```
/*
 * a JSON Parser class to get JSON from URL. This class supports two http request   methods GET and POST to get json from url.
 * 
 */
 public class JSONParser {


    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }
 // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method

            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.i("postData", httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.i("value is for POST", is.toString());

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.i("value is for GET", is.toString());
            }     
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
     // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

`

Here is my EditProduct code:

```
public class EditProduct extends FragmentActivity{

//  EditText inputName;
//    EditText inputPrice;
//    EditText inputDesc;
//    EditText inputQty;
ImageView preview;
ImageButton camera;
public static Bitmap bm;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;
String pid;


EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
EditText txtQty;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://myweb.com/myproject/get_product_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://myweb.com/myproject/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://myweb.com/myproject/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
public static final String TAG_QTY = "qty";

private Uri fileUri;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY=2;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

static File mediaFile;
static String mCurrentPhotoPath;

static JSONObject product;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_products);
 // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

//camera button
    camera=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

    //Camera button event
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            selectImage();
            //galleryAddPic();

        }
    });

}









/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProduct.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread

                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> paramse = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    paramse.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", paramse);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());
                    try {
                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                         product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);



                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // product with this pid found
        // Edit Text
       txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       txtPrice =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
       txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
       txtQty=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
       preview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

    // display product data in EditText
       try {
        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
       txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
       txtQty.setText(product.getString(TAG_QTY));
       preview.setImageBitmap(viewImage(product.getString(TAG_IMAGE)));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProduct.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
        String img=preview.toString();
        String qty=txtQty.getText().toString();

        //Check Log untuk setiap nilai di atas yaww..
        Log.d("Nilai String name lepas Saving",name);
        Log.d("Nilai String price lepas Saving",price);
        Log.d("Nilai String desc lepas Saving",description);
        Log.d("Nilai String img lepas Saving",img);
        Log.d("Nilai String qty lepas Saving",qty);
        Log.d("Nilai String pid lepas Saving",pid);

        try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_IMAGE,img));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_QTY,qty));

        //Nak cek value params ade ke x
        System.out.println(params);


        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);


        Log.d("Saving Response", json.toString());
        // check json success tag

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {

                System.out.println("Fuck not updated shit!");
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProduct.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();

                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Here is my AddNewProduct code

```
public class AddProducts extends Fragment{

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;
EditText inputQty;
String image_str;
ImageView preview;
//    Fragment fragment=this;
Bitmap bm;
String media_photo_file;
String photo_file;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product ="http://myweb.com/myproject   /create_product.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private Uri fileUri;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY=2;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
static File mediaFile;
static String mCurrentPhotoPath;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.add_products);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View aV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_products,container,false);
//      TextView tV1=(TextView)aV.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     inputName=(EditText)aV.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
//      TextView tV2=(TextView)aV.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    inputDesc=(EditText)aV.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
//      TextView tV3=(TextView)aV.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
     inputPrice=(EditText)aV.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ImageButton camera=(ImageButton)aV.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
//      ImageButton gallery=(ImageButton)aV.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    preview=(ImageView)aV.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
//      TextView tV4=(TextView)aV.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    inputQty=(EditText)aV.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final ImageButton addItem=(ImageButton)aV.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);



    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            selectImage();
            //galleryAddPic();

        }
    });
    // addItem button click event
    addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            if (bm==null){ /
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sila Isi Semua Tempat Kosong Syaithonn..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{

            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            //addItem.setEnabled(true)  ;
            }
        }
    });




    return aV;



}

/**
 * Button AddItem
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
        String qty=inputQty.getText().toString();
        String image_str = getImageString( bm);

        //Check Log for image_str value;
        Log.d("Value for String image_str", image_str);

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", qty));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("img", image_str));

        System.out.println(params);
     // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
     // check for success tag
       try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                getActivity().finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
}

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}

}
```

Here is my PHP script for addnewproduct (create):

```
  <?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

 // array for JSON response
 $response = array();

 // check for required fields
 if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])&&      isset($_POST['qty'] )&& isset($_POST['img'] ) ) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$image=$_POST['img'];



// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description,qty,image )  VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description', '$qty','$image' )");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is my deleteproduct php script

```
                            <?php

/*
 * Following code will delete a product from table
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$pid = $_POST['pid'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql update row with matched pid
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");

// check if row deleted or not
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    // successfully updated
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully deleted";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

My big problem is, whenever I run and wanted to update my product details, the data inside the MySQL is not updated at all. My update product code starts here :

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProduct.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
```

which is part of my EditProductCode.

I've also checked if the data is null but everything seems find. Here is myLogcat when I run the SaveProductDetails class above

```
10-17 09:46:59.760: D/Nilai String name lepas Saving(7728): shiyh update
10-17 09:46:59.760: D/Nilai String price lepas Saving(7728): 3.00
10-17 09:46:59.760: D/Nilai String desc lepas Saving(7728): afagfeag
10-17 09:46:59.760: D/Nilai String img lepas Saving(7728):    android.widget.ImageView{137dff73 V.ED.... ......I. 10,60-170,180 #7f08005a app:id/imagePreview}
10-17 09:46:59.760: D/Nilai String qty lepas Saving(7728): 3.00
10-17 09:46:59.760: D/Nilai String pid lepas Saving(7728): 11
10-17 09:46:59.760: I/System.out(7728): [pid=11, name=shiyh update, price=3.00,   description=afagfeag, image=android.widget.ImageView{137dff73 V.ED.... ......I.      10,60-170,180 #7f08005a app:id/imagePreview}, qty=3.00]
10-17 09:46:59.863: I/Choreographer(7728): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be   doing too much work on its main thread.
10-17 09:46:59.969: I/art(7728): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed  2613(116KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 689% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 3.561ms total 119.584ms
10-17 09:46:59.991: I/postData(7728): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10-17 09:46:59.991: I/value is for POST(7728):   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@1527e9eb
10-17 09:46:59.993: D/Saving Response(7728): {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}
10-17 09:46:59.994: I/System.out(7728): Fuck not updated shit!
```

Here is my PHP script for updating the data supposed POST by the SaveProductDetails class

```
<?php 
/*
 * Following code will update a product information
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

 // array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price'])  &&   isset($_POST['description'] )&& isset($_POST['img'] )&& isset($_POST['qty'] ) ) {

  $pid = $_POST['pid'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];
  $base=$_POST['img'];
 $qty = $_POST['qty'];
// include db connect class
//require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql update row with matched pid
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name = '$name', price = '$price',  description = '$description', image='$base', qty='$qty' WHERE pid = $pid" );

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully updated
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

I have no problem when i want to delete the product or create new product. The only problem I had is when i'm using UPDATE in the Php script for updating the data. Could anyone please guide me why I am not able to update my data from android JSON to my MYSql database using the UPDATE method?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'm truncanting some of the codes due to want save the char limits..i've been edited the location you mentioned just now..it's not the codes problem..it was my mistake pasting the code to the asking box here

Comment: @MarcB i'm aware of that since this is my trial to understand how the php and json and mysql working together..thanks for the information too..=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attention !!
EditProduct code.

```
private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
...
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_IMAGE,img));
//TAG_IMAGE="image";
```

PHP script.

```
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price'])  && isset($_POST['description'] )&& isset($_POST['img'] )&& isset($_POST['qty'] ) ) {

//but $_POST['img'] is not existing
```

Comment: sir/maam, you really save my life! It's help to solve my problems..Thank you very much..really appreciated it..

Comment: ooooh! i do not know, i am hero that saves lifes. Sometimes just look through different eyes. Therefore is here Stackoverflow. I am glad to help.